# Python - Web Scrape - Searching String for exact match using entries within a list

Tags: python, string, list, search, beautifulsoup

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this issue.  I'm trying to search a title and extract the calibre of the rifle / shotgun / whatever from the title - With some help its matured to this

The title would be this for example:

**Investarm 410 gauge 100L**

however as im using

```
if calibre in gun_calibre:
```

Its producing the output: 10 gauge

Due to there obviously being a 10 gauge as well as 410 gauge within my list of calibres.

Would anyone know how i can search this string for an exact match on the calibre rather than performing basically a contains search (affectively)

The last thought was that sorting it by length would have rectified this issue but unfortunately it has not.

''''

```
fa_calibre = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]')
gun_calibre = fa_calibre.text if fa_calibre else ''

calibres = ['4 Gauge', '4 gauge', '4G', '4 G', '6 Gauge', '6 gauge', '6G', '6 G', '8 Gauge', '8 gauge', '8G', '8 G', '10 Gauge', '10 gauge', '10G', '10 G', '12 Gauge', '12 gauge', '12G', '12 G', '14 Gauge', '14  gauge', '14G', '14 G', '16 Gauge', '16  gauge', '16G', '16 G', '20 Gauge', '20 gauge', '20G', '20 G', '28 Gauge', '28  gauge', '28G', '28 G', '410 Gauge', '410  gauge', '410G', '410 G', '.17 HMR', '.17hmr', '.17 hmr', '.22 LR', '.22lr', '.22 lr', '.22 WMR' '.22WMR', '.22 wmr', '.22wmr', '.17 Hornet', '.17Hornet', '.17 HORNET', '.17HORNET', '.17 MACH II', '.17 MACH 2', '.17MACH II', '.17MACH 2', '.17 Mach II', '.17 Mach 2', '.17mach II' '.17 REM', '.17 REM Fireball', '.17 WSM', '.204 Ruger', '.22 Hornet', '.22 Magnum', '.22 Short', '.22-250', '.220 Swift', '.222', '.223', '.243', '.25-06', '.257 Weatherby Magnum', '.260 REM', '.270', '.270 WSM', '.275', '.30-06', '.30-30', '.300 ACC Blackout', '.300 Ultra Mag', '.300 Win Mag', '.300 WSM', '.303', '.308', '.338 Blaser Magnum', '.338 Lap Mag', '.338 Win Mag', '.357 Magnum', '.375 H&H Mag', '.38 / .357 Magnum', '.40-09', '.408 Cheytac', '.416 REM Mag', '.416 Rigby', '.44 Magnum', '.44-40', '.444', 'Multiple in Stock', '.45 Long Colt', '.45-60', '.45-70', '.45-90', '.45-120', '.45-70 Govt.', '.450', '.458 Win Mag', '.470 Nitro Express', '.50 BMG', '.577', '6.5mm Grendel', '6.5mm Creedmore', '6.5x284', '6.5x47 Lapua', '6.5x54', '6.5x55', '6mm BR', '7.5x55', '7.62', '7.62x39', '7.62x51', '7.62x54R', '7.92', '7mm REM MAG', '7mm-08', '7x57', '7x64', '8.5x63', '8mm REM MAG', '8x57', '8x68', '9.3x62', '9.3x74R', 'Multiple Calibre', '9mm RF', '12 G & 20 G', '20 G & 28 G', '20 G & 28 G & 410 G', '28G & 410 G', '.177', '.177 (BB)', '.20', '.22', '.25', '.30', '4.5mm', '6mm (BB)', '.177', '.177 (BB)', '.20', '.22', '.25', '.30', '6mm', '.32', '.32 ACP', '.32 AUTO', '.357', '.357 MAGNUM', '.38 SPECIAL', '.38 SUPER AUTO', '.38 AUTO', '.40', '.44', '.44 MAGNUM', '.45', '.45 ACP', '9MM', '1in', '9MM RF', '.22 SHOT', '.22 GAUGE', '28G & 410G', '12G & 20G', '16G & 8X57', '12G & 20G', '20G & 28G', '20G & 28G & 410G', 'FLARE', '.357', '.22 MAGNUM']

for calibre in calibres:
   if re.search(calibre, gun_calibre):
      gun_calibre = calibre
   else:
      gun_calibre = calibre

array = [guntrader_id, gun_title, gun_makes, gun_models, gun_calibre, gun_licences, gun_orients, gun_barrels, gun_barrels_fractions, gun_stocks_whole, gun_stocks_fractions, gun_choke1, gun_choke2, gun_origins, gun_triggers, gun_ejections, gun_scopes, gun_serials, gun_stocknos, gun_conditions, gun_description, gun_price]

print(array)
```

''''

Comment: You can use regex for this, it should be straightforward.

Comment: @AMC does regex work while using lists to search strings?

Comment: _does regex work while using lists to search strings?_ That depends on what exactly you mean, but it should work just fine here.

Comment: I have a question about your program/the task at hand: It looks like the list `calibres` contains different ways of referring to the same calibre. Wouldn't it be better to group them up somehow, so that you can manipulate identical calibres regardless of how they're written?

Comment: The regex search works with the example from https://www.guru99.com/python-regular-expressions-complete-tutorial.html regarding their search example. but it is printing the whole title string rather than the actual calibre from the list it is matching too.  any idea why?

Comment: Difficult to say without the code.

Comment: @AMC - updated code with what i'm currently looking at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206244/discussion-between-amc-and-andrew-glass).

Comment: @AMC joined chat